# Wordpress - Send email on Post meta value change

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I want to accomplice the following. I want to automatically send an email on post publish/update when a certain post field value has changed.

- In a post
- A ACF field that has 4 options, lets say `[ 'draft', 'ready for group1', 'ready for group 2', 'ready']`
- If this field gets changed on post update send email to "this" email address.

I think I need to know 2 things for this.
 - How and where (what action) do I need to insert custom code on post publish/update
 - How to compare new post data to old state (and is this possible/availible in the action above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook onto `acf/save_post` for this purpose. Read the documentation here: 
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Since you want the callback to fire **before** the values are stored, in order to compare the old value against the new one, keep in mind to add a priority of less than 10. Assuming the field with 4 options has the field key `field_4afd4af14415f`:

```
function on_acf_post_save($post_id) {
  $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
  if ($post_type === 'your-post-type') {
    $old_val = get_field('field_4afd4af14415f', $post_id);
    $new_val = $_POST['acf']['field_4afd4af14415f'];
    if ($old_val != $new_val) {
      // Send desired mail in here:
      // wp_mail(...);
    }
  }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'on_acf_post_save', 5, 1); // priority = 5
```

If your ACF field isn't at the top level, but inside a Group or Repeater, you will have to adapt the code reading from the `$_POST['acf']` and `get_field()` result.